# Wildfly 11 - WebService: Force No-Caching

Tags: sapui5, browser-cache, wildfly-11

I am running a totally casual WebPage on my Wildfly 11.
Now, if I want to update my Application, what can I do, to force the browser of the client to use my new files instead of the old, cached ones?

The Problem in particular is a file of mine, which is the first file to be called when someone accesses my page, it's called "Component.js". I am not allowed to rename this file (in case you are thinking of cache busting as a solution).

I simply need a way, when http gets the file, to tell it somehow, not to use the cached file. On client side of course.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give much more information. What is a "totally casual webpage"?

What does 'components.js" do? Code?

What are you displaying in the browser which needs updating?

Is it an EJB application using JSF and Facelets (XHTML)?